# Time difference between two columns storing only time in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns (session_starttime & session_endtime) whose data type is a text. As seen in the image, it is only the time part that is stored and no date.

[image: I have two columns (session_starttime & session_endtime) whose data type is a text. As seen in the image, it is only the time part that is stored and no date.]

I am struggling to get a session duration in seconds. The ultimate goal is to get the average time per session.

I have tried the code below but it did not work

````sql
select 
avg(datediff('second', session_endtime,session_starttime)) as Average_settlement_time
from user_sessions ```
````

ERROR

> (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function datediff(unknown, text, text) does not exist
> LINE 8: avg(datediff('second', session_endtime,session_starttime)) a...

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you. Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS.

Comment: The error message looks like PostgreSQL one. If this is correct then you must cast the string-type time values to TIME datatype explicitly before applying the function. PS. In PostgreSQL the function DATEDIFF() not exists at all. Substract then convert the INTERVAL datatype to seconds.

Comment: In Postgres you would  simply use `session_endtime - session_starttime`

Comment: Thank you so much @Akina, I have implemented the change and it worked.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. This works as long as I am able to cast the text to time

Comment: If you are storing a time, the column should be converted to the `time` data type.

Comment: Can a session start at `23:55:00` and end at `00:05:00`? Can a session last more than 24 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have a `datediff` function.

You can explicitly cast both columns to `time` and then subtract them, resulting in an `INTERVAL` result:

```sql
SELECT session_endtime::TIME - session_starttime::TIME
FROM mytable
-- E.g. returns 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 40.00 secs for the first row
```

If you want a number of seconds instead of an `INTERVAL`, you can extract the EPOCH from it:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM session_endtime::TIME - session_starttime::TIME)
FROM mytable
-- E.g. returns 100 for the first row
```